# Active Model Serializer not render my models

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4.1, active-model-serializers, rails-api

I am trying to integrate Active Model Serializer to render JSON elements with relations.

I follow the documentation on this address: http://rubydoc.info/gems/active_model_serializers

I am not sure if I am doing something wrong but it looks like serializers are not working. Do I need to make more steps?

I install the gem, generate the serializer and add relation.

Can you guide me, please??

My project is in this repo:

https://github.com/dwdsolutions/argo

Best Regards

Answer (score 3):

You're using the 0.9.0 version. Try to change it to 0.8.0

Comment: Thank you, that works! But what is the problem with use the 0.9.0 version?

Comment: 0.10.0, the latest version on master on this time, will be based on 0.8.0. [One of the maintainers even called 0.9.0 a dead end](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/issues/670#issuecomment-59813913).

I've had a lot of issues with 0.9.x including infinite loops ('stack level too deep' errors) and difficulty passing parameters and options to serializers. Downgrading to 0.8.0 solved all my problems.

Answer (score 2):

Alex is right, I tried using v0.9.0 earlier and was unable to get it working per the existing documentation.

The main github repo does state to use v0.8.0 if you are familiar with the gem (https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/tree/master#maintenance-please-read). At any rate, once you get it working, you shouldn't need to manually specify your serializers since they're named properly compared to your models and controllers.

i.e. you can remove the trailing option of this line:

```
render json: @travel, serializer: TravelSerializer
```

And make it just:

```
render json: @travel
```